# C++ Save Bitmap file

Tags: c++

I'm working on an application that captures the user's screen and saved in bitmap. 
I'm having problems when creating the file

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

I am getting the following error in filename:
**argument of type "LPCSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"**

below is the code:

```
    #include <olectl.h>

bool saveBitmap(LPCSTR filename, HBITMAP bmp, HPALETTE pal)
{
    bool result = false;
    PICTDESC pd;

    pd.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof(PICTDESC);
    pd.picType = PICTYPE_BITMAP;
    pd.bmp.hbitmap = bmp;
    pd.bmp.hpal = pal;

    LPPICTURE picture;
    HRESULT res = OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pd, IID_IPicture, false,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&picture));

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res))
        return false;

    LPSTREAM stream;
    res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, &stream);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res))
    {
        picture->Release();
        return false;
    }

    LONG bytes_streamed;
    res = picture->SaveAsFile(stream, true, &bytes_streamed);

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res) || !file)
    {
        stream->Release();
        picture->Release();
        return false;
    }

    HGLOBAL mem = 0;
    GetHGlobalFromStream(stream, &mem);
    LPVOID data = GlobalLock(mem);

    DWORD bytes_written;

    result = !!WriteFile(file, data, bytes_streamed, &bytes_written, 0);
    result &= (bytes_written == static_cast<DWORD>(bytes_streamed));

    GlobalUnlock(mem);
    CloseHandle(file);

    stream->Release();
    picture->Release();

    return result;
}

void CaptureScreen()
{
    int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,
        nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);
    BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight,
        hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    LPCSTR fname = "c:\\Users\\hom3r\\Downloads\\image.bmp";
    HPALETTE hpal = NULL;
    saveBitmap(fname, hCaptureBitmap, hpal);

    ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have UNICODE defined in your project, meaning that you are using the wide-character version of the Windows API.  LPC[W]STR is Long Pointer to C [Wide] String.

You can either remove the UNICODE define to use the 8-bit ASCII interface, or better, use wide characters throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `file_name` from `LPCSTR` to `LPCWSTR` using ATL (Active Template Library).

Hence, replace

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

with

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(A2W(filename), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

`A2W` (ANSI to wide) is defined in `<atlbase.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TCHAR or wchar_t type. See similar questions at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112633/converting-from-lpcwstr-to-lpcstr) and [MSDN.net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab61419c-7187-4fc1-8892-e2119f594683/lots-of-lpcwstr-errors)